# Oracle: First occurrence of a particular character in a string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a department table. I want to display the position of occurrence of character "C" in each of the department names. What would be the query? Please help me. By the way, i am using oracle 10g.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Do you mean the first occurrence if any?

Comment: If there is a department name like accounting then it will display 2 and 3 as "C" is located at the 2nd and 3rd position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `InStr` funstion(s):

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1103.htm

Your query could be something like this:

```
  select Name,
         InStr(Name, 'C')
    from Departments
```